# Adding paramter in linear model improves significance?

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I'm fairly new to linear models so I'd like to have an explanation for this phenomenon.

I calculated two linear models with R. The first one outputs this:

```
lm(formula = Gries_PM10_value ~ Gries_PM10_value_lag1 + Gries_LUTE_value + 
    Kalkleiten_WIGE_value)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q 
-23.1273  -4.8379  -0.2452   5.1194 
     Max 
 24.6230 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)           15.83196    2.05175
Gries_PM10_value_lag1  0.47306    0.06918
Gries_LUTE_value      -0.24091    0.16299
Kalkleiten_WIGE_value -1.65277    0.53690
                      t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             7.716 1.73e-12 ***
Gries_PM10_value_lag1   6.838 2.04e-10 ***
Gries_LUTE_value       -1.478  0.14155    
Kalkleiten_WIGE_value  -3.078  0.00249 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  
  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’
  0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.866 on 146 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2966,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2821 
F-statistic: 20.52 on 3 and 146 DF,  p-value: 3.773e-11
```

The parameters describe two places, Gries and Kalkleiten which are 7km apart, then PM10 is a measure for fine particles, LUTE the temperature, WIGE the wind speed and PM10_lag1 the PM10 value from last day.

So this model behaved like I'd expect. The previous-day values of PM10 is very significant, the wind speed is also significant but the air temperature not so much.

But then I added the air temperature for Gries and I got:

```
lm(formula = Gries_PM10_value ~ Gries_PM10_value_lag1 + Gries_LUTE_value + 
    Kalkleiten_WIGE_value + Kalkleiten_LUTE_value)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q 
-19.0517  -4.2531  -0.0896   4.4151 
     Max 
 19.3326 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)           22.85199    1.94546
Gries_PM10_value_lag1  0.28269    0.06309
Gries_LUTE_value      -2.68195    0.34075
Kalkleiten_WIGE_value -1.95956    0.45343
Kalkleiten_LUTE_value  2.52227    0.32231
                      t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            11.746  < 2e-16 ***
Gries_PM10_value_lag1   4.481 1.50e-05 ***
Gries_LUTE_value       -7.871 7.49e-13 ***
Kalkleiten_WIGE_value  -4.322 2.86e-05 ***
Kalkleiten_LUTE_value   7.826 9.65e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’
  0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6.618 on 145 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5054,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4918 
F-statistic: 37.05 on 4 and 145 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now all the coefficients are strongly significant. Overall, this model seems to fit a lot better even though I wouldn't expect the air temperature to make such a big difference. What's the explanation behind this?

Comment: I always search for answers to this (and related questions) using the keywords [regression significant not](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20significant%20not&searchOn=3).  It picks up dozens of interesting threads on the topic of significance changing when variables are added and removed from models.

Comment: @whuber OK thanks, I'll look into them. I didn't know that this was such a widely discussed topic here.

Comment: Just about anything important concerning ordinary least squares multiple regression has been well covered over the last 12 years and 200,000 questions!